# Display Matplotlib Audio Graph Inside Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I was trying to insert a plot graph I get from an audio file into my tkinter root window however I'm not sure how to do it or which widget to use to display.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x400")
root.title("SOUNDART")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg="#1d1d1d")

rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read("example.wav")
plt.plot(data)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a complete example.

You must use canvas to embed the chart and above all use an object-oriented approach.

Audio file is in the same dir of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

try:
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2Tk as nav_tool
except:
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import  NavigationToolbar2TkAgg as nav_tool
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import gridspec

from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)
        #self.geometry("700x400")
        self.title("SOUNDART")
        self.init_ui()
        self.set_plot()
       
    def init_ui(self):

        f = ttk.Frame(padding = 8)
        fig = Figure()
        fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.10, right=0.96, left=0.08, top=0.95, wspace=0.10)
        self.plt = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor=('xkcd:light grey'))
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, f)
        toolbar = nav_tool(canvas, f)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def set_plot(self):

        
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

        my_file = 'example.wav'

        samplerate, data = wavfile.read(my_file)

        length = data.shape[0] / samplerate

        samplerate, data = wavfile.read(my_file)

        time = np.linspace(0., length, data.shape[0])

        self.plt.plot(time, data[:, 0], label="Left channel")

        self.plt.plot(time, data[:, 1], label="Right channel")

        self.plt.legend()

        self.plt.set_xlabel("Time [s]")

        self.plt.set_ylabel("Amplitude")

    def on_exit(self):
        if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]